# Why does the google map api render the map partially 2nd time around?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-maps-api-3

I have this js code to render my map :

```
function loadMap(address)
{
    console.log(address);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ "address": address }, function (results, status)
    {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(53.681602, -1.911672); // default.
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            pos = results[0].geometry.location;
        } else {
            alert("Error : Unable to locate!");
        }

        console.log(pos);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: pos,
            zoom: 10,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP },
            mapTypeControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
        });
    });
}
```

Problem is first time it executes the map shows fine, but the 2nd time, the postcode is still the same, the lat/long come out the same yet the map shows partially, with only about a 1/4th of it showing in the top-left of the div.

Anything I am doing incorrectly?

**EDIT:**

After jterrys suggestions it still looks the same :

[image]

HTML/CSS :

```
#mapCanvas
{
    width: 655px;
        height: 472px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
```

I am using JQuery 2.0, I have also had this before when I was using <2.0

Comment: Are you using any other 3rd party libraries (`jQuery`, et al.)? I've had troubles with things like `jQuery UI tabs` and Google Maps rendering incorrectly.

Comment: Yep, those look like jQuery tabs to me. I'll update my answer below with what I had to do to solve this same problem.

Comment: What do you mean "the second time"? Please explain what are you doing exactly. It might be that it just the map needs to be refreshed because the div container changes size.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the `mapoptions` and `map` just once, outside of the `geocode` callback - *then* update the marker instead of recreating the entire map.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/rEfKS/7/)** showing one geocode, then another, and back to the first... `div` positioning looks normal.

---

Per the updated question, **[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joeterry/L4kP3/1/)** waits for the actual activation of the second tab before rendering the map... I had the exact same issue when creating my tabbed map.

```
$("#two").click(function() {
    init();
}
```

This could be much more robust and tie into the `tabs` events that are fired when users interact with them, but this quick example illustrates the solution.

As a side bonus, this also conserves the resources needed to display the map (as well as any quota) until the user actually activates the tab!

Comment: Unfortunately not, the issue after much digging is something to do with the IE cache, after changes it was working fine in chrome, yet ie would mess up every 2nd time, but after a force clean of cache it would be fine for another go. In the end I gave up on IE 10.